# How to insert text at selected position inside <p> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I need a function to insert text at cursor position inside the `<p>` tag and get back focus on the same

I have the following code for `textarea`, but it is not working for `<p>` tag :

```
var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, caretPos);
var back = (txtarea.value).substring(txtarea.selectionEnd,txtarea.value.length);
txtarea.value = front + text + back;
caretPos = caretPos + text.length;
txtarea.selectionStart = caretPos;
txtarea.selectionEnd = caretPos;
txtarea.focus();
txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
```

Comment: please share your html also.

Comment: it is having only<p> tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function that does what you describe, works on most element tags (`<p>`, `<div>`, `<span>`, etc...):

```js
function addTextToElement(element, insertText) {
  var originalContent = element.innerHTML;

  var selection = document.getSelection();
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

  var originalStart = range.startOffset;
  var originalEnd = range.endOffset;

  var front = originalContent.substring(0, originalStart);
  var back = originalContent.substring(originalEnd, originalContent.length);

  element.innerHTML = front + insertText + back;
}
```

```html
Step 1: <input type="text" id="contentToAdd" placeholder="Type something here" /> <br/>
Step 2: place cursor / select some text in the p-tag below:
<p contenteditable="true" id="testPTag" style="background-color: cyan">0123456789</p>
<button onclick="addTextToElement(document.getElementById('testPTag'), document.getElementById('contentToAdd').value)">Press me to insert text</button>
<br/>
```

`<p>` tags are not input text elements, they do not have a selectionStart or selectionEnd attribute. You can however make use of `document.getSelection()` to read the currently selection and selected ranges.

Furthermore, these tags does not rely on their `.value` property for displaying, but instead `.innerHTML`.

In the example above, I also added `contenteditable="true"` to the `<p>` tag, this allows you to edit `<p>` tags like in text area. This is not neccessary, but allows you to at least see the cursor.

Note that this does not work on Internet Explorer 9 or earlier.

Comment: when is string replaced it loses the cursor position, any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [HTMLTextAreaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement), `selectionStart` is not for any other [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement).

But you can make a `<p>` element editable with [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable). Then the `<p>` behaves like a `textarea`.

Comment: `Then the <p> behaves like a textarea. ` Not really, it still doesn't have `selectionStart` and attributes alike. From the DOM side, it's still a normal HTMLElement.